Meaning of "schon" in "Ich schätze schon."
I came across the phrase "Ich schätze schon." (See below for full context.) The meaning is "I suppose so," or "I guess so," or "Apparently so." But I would have guessed "Ich schätze so," as the equivalent German expression. Why is "schon" used here instead of "so"? I know that "schon" is sometimes used as a modal particle, and can have many other meanings besides, but I'm having a hard time matching this example to a meaning listed in DWDS. Is "schätzen schon" a fixed phrase?
Context: This occurs in Season 2, Episode 1 of "The Lincoln Laywer" series on Netflix. A Homicide detective is interviewing a suspect who said he went into the victim's bathroom and used her towel. The detective says that must be how the suspect's DNA got on the victim's towel, and the suspect responds "Ich schätze schon." But the expression seems to be very common elsewhere.
PS. Just to clarify things a bit, here is a transcript of the German (CC) subtitles:

Suspect: Ich benutzte ein Handtuch, das im Bad hing.
Detective: Und so geriet Ihre DNS aufs Handtuch.
Suspect: Ich schätze schon.
Tja, und dann... Dann bin ich weg.


"Ich schätze so" would be a too literal translation of the English phrase that wouldn't be used in German. As far as I know, the fixed phrase "I guess so" is basically a short form of "I guess it is so". There's no such fixed, shortened form in German. You would need to use the "full phrase", for example

Ich schätze, es ist so.
I guess it is so. / I guess it is like that.

The "schon" in your example is in fact a modal particle. Going by the context you provided, I would read it as a weakening of the statement. The suspect has no real way of knowing if that's the way the DNA got on the towel, (probably) no expertise to judge etc. So, you could translate this

Ich schätze schon.

as

I guess that's possible, yeah shrugs.

with a significant subtext of "I have no idea, but as far as I can tell it's possible, if you as the expert say so..."
In Duden you find this usage as point 5, in DWDS as point 4b.
It may be worthwile to notice that the suspect already weakens his statement by using the verb "schätzen", "to guess" or "to estimate". This already comes with reduced expectations to the statements veracity, exactness etc.

It's interesting that there seems to be different interpretations of the same phrase, but this answer seems to fit the context best. So the subtext here is something like "Sure, if you say so," even if the suspect doesn't actually say that, and German is able to include that subtext when it's not expressed in English.

The word »schon« expresses an intensification of the meaning of the sentence. By adding this word, you emphasize that you do not mean the opposite.

A: Ich verzichte lieber auf die Torte, ich bin eh viel zu dick.
B: Mit ist das egal. Ich nehme schon ein Stück.


A: Ich glaube nicht, dass die DNA durch diese Berührung auf das Handtuch gekommen ist.
B: Ich glaube schon.

So, if the detective says »Ich schätze schon«, then she emphasizes her believe without mentioning other methods of contamination.

The word »so« on the other hand does not emphasize anything. It selects one of many possibilities.

A: Magst du lieber ein kleines oder ein großes Stück Torte?
B, while grabbing the biggest piece: Ich nehme so ein Stück.


A: Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie die DNA auf das Handtuch gekommen sein könnte.
B, while touching the towel: Ich glaube so.

So, if the detective says »Ich schätze so«, then she doesn't emphasize anything. Instead she selects one specific method of contamination from many other methods.

It's the suspect that says it, so that may change the context. You may ask, why would the detective be asking the suspect to interpret forensic evidence? That seemed odd to me too. In any case, the suspect is agreeing with the detective on this point.

I read the dialogue as the detective presenting that explanation as doubtful, and the suspect stating that nevertheless this was was had happened.

DWDS describes a matching meaning in the section II 3, in my opinion the best match is 3a:

bekräftigt eine Aussage, gegen die ein Einwand erhoben worden ist, ein Zweifel bestanden hat

I would translate it to English nevertheless; there are some doubts or reasons against, but the speaker considers them as insufficient. (I see schon as a quite weak affirmation, but DWDS does not state this.)
Another example:

A: Wer kommt mit ins Kino?
B: Ich nicht.
C: Ich schon. (despite rejection by B)


As I mentioned in another comment, the suspect is agreeing with the detective here; there are no other possibilities mentioned.

"Schon" is a so-called "mood particle". It carries no real meaning of its own, it just states a certain stance of the speaker. Every language has them. Historically these particles were single words, nowadays whole phrases can serve that purpose.
For instance:

You can do that.
You can do that, indeed.
You can do that, FWIW.

In your example, the speaker answer to a question:

Ich schätze schon.

Would he have left that out, it would be slightly unidiomatical, but a simple agreement with the interrogator. "You think so?" "Yes, I do."
But in fact, the suspect assumes, that the detective will not really believe that to be the case. So, first, he doesn't really agree with the detective but only tentatively so. He doesn't say something like "Ja, genau so wars!" (Yes, exactly that!), but rather "Ich schätze" (I guess). And second - anticipating the counter arguments he might hear from the detective - he insists of it being so and reinforces it with "schon", something like this hypothetical dialogue:

D: So kam ihre DNS aufs Handtuch?
S: Ja, das glaube/schätze ich.
D: Das glauben sie ja selber nicht!
S: ich glaube/schätze schon.

The first line of the suspect and the second line of the detective don't really happen but are anticipated by the suspect, so he uses his second line immediately. The "schon" defends against doubts being cast - even before they are cast.
